# how to upload mp3 file and get its duration in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I'd like to upload a MP3 file in Laravel and then get the duration of the MP3. Here's my code, but it's not working:

```
$music_file = Input::file('audio_path');
$file_music = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s')."-".$music_file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('assets/music/' . $file_music);
$path = $music_file->getRealPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

for moving MP3

```
$music_file = Input::file('audio_path');
$file_music = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s')."-".$music_file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path('assets/music/' . $file_music);
$music_file->move($path,$file_music);
```

Answer (score 0):

After observing many doubts on this subject I will leave here a step by step with the solution I found for this problem.

For this we will use the getid3 package, a media file parser. 
This solution was tested on Laravel 6.x, but it is compatible with several versions of Laravel.

1 - To install it on Laravel using the Composer, at the root of the project using the console type:

```
$ composer require james-heinrich/getid3
```

In this example we will create an endpoint to send an .mp3 file and return its duration.

2 - Create a Route to send the file:

```
Route::post('media', 'FilesController@media');
```

3 - Create a Controller to get the file and return the duration:

```
class FilesController extends Controller
{
    public function media(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('upload');
        if(!empty($request->file('upload'))) {
            $getID3 = new \getID3;
            $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($file);
            $len= @$ThisFileInfo['playtime_string']; // playtime in minutes:seconds, formatted string
            return $len;
        }
    }
```

4 - Sending the file:

Test using POSTMAN (good to check if everything in Laravel is OK):

[image]

Note: the upload field in POSTMAN is of type FILE.

Using Curl / PHP

```
<?php

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://localhost/api/media",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('upload'=> new CURLFILE('/home/fellipe/Desktop/android-timeless.mp3')),
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept: application/json"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```